# Trying to activate venv in PyCharm project with git

Tags: python, pycharm, virtualenv, git-bash, python-venv

I've been trying for days to get a virtual environment for my Python project set up in PyCharm. I've seen a bunch of stuff online, but nothing seems to work for me.

Before I start anything, I run `which python` in my **git bash** terminal, which returns:

```
//asc/fs/homedir/<my_account>/pycharm/<repo_name>/Scripts/python
```

Then, when I try to officially activate the venv, I run `source ./venv/Scripts/activate`, which promptly fails with error:

```
bash: basename: command not found
()
```

After I do this, I lose the little tag at the end of my bash terminal dirpath that normally shows the current git branch I'm on. I don't see `(venv)`, which seems to be the expected behavior based on other stackoverflow posts. There is nothing appended to the current directory path of my terminal.

I can no longer run a number of standard bash commands. Running `which python` yields

```
bash: which: command not found
()
```

Is this some sort of PATH issue? Am I successfully activating the venv at all? (What is the '()' that shows up after every command?)

Answer (score 0):

Supposedly this is an issue with **pip on NETWORK drives.**

I fixed the issue by moving my virtual environment to my native `C:` drive, and then went through the normal config process-

- set my PyCharm Python interpreter to this NEW venv in my `C:` drive
- updated my PyCharm run/debug configuration to use this new interpreter
- restarted terminal
- installed all the necessary deps with pip
- Good to go! (now I can run pytest + other commands on this local project)